# Convert multidimensional Array (Object[,]) to string[]

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm stuck in an easy task: convert an multidimensional Array (Object[,]) in a monodimensional string[].

Long story short: I'm reading an excel file using a com library which returns a dynamic type casted to Object[,] at runtime.

```
SortedSet<string> rows = new SortedSet<string>();
for (int i = 3; i <= 5; i++) 
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A"+i, "J"+i);
    Array cells = (Array) range.Cells.Value; // value return dynamic [,] -> Object[,] -> cast to Array[,]
    string[] rowCells = ConvertArrayToStringArray(cells); // 
    rows.Add(string.Join("\t", rowCells));
}
return string.Join("\r\n", rows);
```

Since Array[,] always have 1 row (I read the excel file row by row) I'd like to cast it to a simple string[] (or List) without using another loop in ConvertArrayToStringArray function.

I could read all cells in an action (not row by row like in code above), but I've no idea of how many rows are in excel file.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] rowCells = cells.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for!
Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm ashamed, but I didn't know existance of ".Cast(<T>)".

Comment: @insilenzio, it's an extension method, part of Linq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406.aspx